# stop mutate truncating column column names

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, mutate

I am making a large data frame using `mutate` with lots of `ifelse` conditions. My approach is to not name the columns within mutate because I have many hundreds of these conditions and each time I update one I then have to update them all. Rather I wish to name the columns after the operation outside of `mutate`.

Here is some code outlining what Im trying to do

```
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(20, 100, 1), b = rnorm(20, 100, 1), c = rnorm(20, 100, 1) )

df2 <- df %>%
    mutate(# condition 1
           ifelse((lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 2) - lag(b, 2)) &
                  (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 3) - lag(b, 3)) &
                  (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 4) - lag(b, 4)), 1, 0), 
           # condition 2
           ifelse((lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 2) - lag(b, 2)) &
                  (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 3) - lag(b, 3)) &
                  (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 4) - lag(b, 4)) &
                  (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 5) - lag(b, 5)) &
                  (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 6) - lag(b, 6)), 1, 0),
           # condition 3
           ifelse(a < b, 1, 0),
           .keep = 'none'
           )

c_names <- paste('df', rep(1:ncol(df2), 1), sep = '')
colnames(df2) <- c_names
```

the trouble is `mutate` is truncating the col names of the long `ifelse` conditions `#condition 1` and `#condition 2` and lumping them together as `ifelse(...)` so I end up with only 2 columns instead of 3.

Is there something I can do to prevent this behaviour or a more efficient way of achieving what Im try to do. I want to avoid manually typing out hundreds of column names for each condition every time I need to update the df.I would ideally be able to map the identity of the condition back to the new column name. For e.g.

```
df3 = ifelse(a < b, 1, 0)
```

This is possible when `mutate` doesn't repair the column name

Comment: example data does not have column `c` referred to in example code.

Comment: This looks like it would be much simpler to maintain using a function or two + `purrr::map`, especially if the functions have structure like what you have here.

Comment: Thanks for your input @JonSpring, be great if you could show an example of how to achieve using your suggestion.

Comment: sure, I've added an example -- caveating that I haven't done much testing. it seems dreadful to have to specify your function ranges manually like that, so it would be worth your time to make a function or two that do it for you.

Comment: Cheers. The example ifelse functions I gave were just examples to produce large column names. I have many hundreds of different variable manipulations that cant be reproduced with a simple function like you gave unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the columns in `data.frame`, which does not truncate the names so heavily. (The `mutate` help page notes that the `...` arguments can be *"a data frame or tibble, to create multiple columns in the output."*)

```
df2 <- df %>%
    mutate(
      data.frame(
           # condition 1
           ifelse((lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 2) - lag(b, 2)) &
                  (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 3) - lag(b, 3)) &
                  (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 4) - lag(b, 4)), 1, 0), 
           # condition 2
           ifelse((lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 2) - lag(b, 2)) &
                  (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 3) - lag(b, 3)) &
                  (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 4) - lag(b, 4)) &
                  (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 5) - lag(b, 5)) &
                  (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 6) - lag(b, 6)), 1, 0),
           # condition 3
           ifelse(a < b, 1, 0)
          ),
          .keep = 'none'
        )

c_names <- paste('df', rep(1:ncol(df2), 1), sep = '')
colnames(df2) <- c_names
df2
#    df1 df2 df3
# 1   NA  NA   0
# 2   NA  NA   0
# 3   NA  NA   0
# 4   NA  NA   0
# 5    1  NA   0
# 6    0   0   1
# 7    1   1   1
# 8    1   1   0
# 9    0   0   1
# 10   1   1   0
# 11   0   0   0
# 12   0   0   0
# 13   0   0   1
# 14   1   0   1
# 15   1   0   1
# 16   0   0   1
# 17   0   0   0
# 18   0   0   1
# 19   1   1   1
# 20   1   1   1
```

Comment: including, check.names = FALSE, in data.frame() allows me to also store the id of the inequality in the colname before replacing with generic df1...n identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You could use unique / random column names, UUID for example:

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(20, 100, 1), b = rnorm(20, 100, 1), c = rnorm(20, 100, 1))

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(# condition 1
    "{uuid::UUIDgenerate()}" := 
      ifelse((lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 2) - lag(b, 2)) &
             (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 3) - lag(b, 3)) &
             (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 4) - lag(b, 4)), 1, 0), 
    # condition 2
    "{uuid::UUIDgenerate()}" := 
      ifelse((lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 2) - lag(b, 2)) &
             (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 3) - lag(b, 3)) &
             (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 4) - lag(b, 4)) &
             (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 5) - lag(b, 5)) &
             (lag(a, 1) - lag(c, 1)) < (lag(a, 6) - lag(b, 6)), 1, 0),
    # condition 3
    "{uuid::UUIDgenerate()}" := 
      ifelse(a < b, 1, 0),
    .keep = 'none'
  )
str(df2)
#> 'data.frame':    20 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ 2175b2b7-511f-471a-94d5-d82116b12137: num  NA NA NA 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 ...
#>  $ 07e353a6-58b9-4c50-9c08-2b7c742cf28b: num  NA NA NA 0 NA NA 0 0 1 1 ...
#>  $ a4fb004b-f498-4da0-b60b-1fbf872670a5: num  0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 ...

c_names <- paste('df', rep(1:ncol(df2), 1), sep = '')
colnames(df2) <- c_names

str(df2)
#> 'data.frame':    20 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ df1: num  NA NA NA 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 ...
#>  $ df2: num  NA NA NA 0 NA NA 0 0 1 1 ...
#>  $ df3: num  0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is a great answer, however one drawback that I cannot then identify the identity of the inequality downstream - e.g. if df1 produces a particular result Id like to be able to map that back to the identity of the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

From the first two examples it looks like some of your tests have a common structure and would be better expressed using a function instead of a lot of manually generated code, which is brittle and hard to maintain.

For instance, it seems one structure is `Is prior col1 - prior col2 < all entries in some range of prior col3 - col4?` The first and second test are identical except for the range of rows in their tests.

I haven't tested this much so I'm not guaranteeing anything, but I suspect something like this could save you a lot of time and exasperation.

A further refinement could be to make the column name be a concatenation of the parameters, presuming they are unique. For the moment I've just copied @margusl's approach with `uuid`.

```
compare_func <- function(my_df, col1, col2, lag1, col3, col4, lag_min, lag_max) {
  my_df %>%
    mutate("{uuid::UUIDgenerate()}" := 1*(
      lag({{col1}} - {{col2}}, lag1) < 
        slider::slide_dbl({{col3}} - {{col4}}, ~min(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
                          .before = lag_min, .after = -lag_min)))
}
```

Then your code is much simpler, and each test is specified directly by its parameters:

```
df %>%
  compare_func(a, c, 1, a, b, 4, 2) %>%
  compare_func(a, c, 1, a, b, 6, 2) %>%
  mutate("{uuid::UUIDgenerate()}" := 1*(a < b))
```